# Handling CORS Issues While Extracting User Role from JWT in Spring Boot Applicatio

Tags: cors

The problem is that some of my API endpoints are being blocked by the browser's same-origin policy, which is enforced due to the CORS policy. I've already configured CORS in some parts of my code, but I'm facing issues with the `AuthenticationFilter`.

the login controller and register are working as expected but the user controller won't

here is the code:

```
package com.sd.usermanagement.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.CorsRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;

@Configuration
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                registry.addMapping("/**").allowedOrigins("http://localhost:4200");
            }
        };
    }
}
```

```
package com.sd.usermanagement.security.filter;

import com.sd.usermanagement.security.JWTGenerator;
import jakarta.servlet.Filter;
import jakarta.servlet.FilterChain;
import jakarta.servlet.ServletException;
import jakarta.servlet.ServletRequest;
import jakarta.servlet.ServletResponse;
import jakarta.servlet.annotation.WebFilter;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.io.IOException;

@Component
@WebFilter
public class AuthenticationFilter implements Filter {
    private final JWTGenerator jwtGenerator;

    @Autowired
    public AuthenticationFilter(JWTGenerator jwtGenerator) {
        this.jwtGenerator = jwtGenerator;
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = (HttpServletRequest) servletRequest;
        HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse = (HttpServletResponse) servletResponse;
        String token = httpServletRequest.getHeader("Authorization");
        String requestURI = httpServletRequest.getRequestURI();

        if (requestURI.equals("/api/register") || requestURI.equals("/api/login")
        ) {
            filterChain.doFilter(httpServletRequest, httpServletResponse);
            return;
        }

        if (token == null || !token.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
            httpServletResponse.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
            return;
        }

        String jwtToken = token.replace("Bearer ", "");
        httpServletRequest.setAttribute("jwtToken", jwtToken);

        if (jwtGenerator.isTokenExpired(jwtToken)) {
            httpServletResponse.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
            return;
        }

        filterChain.doFilter(httpServletRequest, httpServletResponse);
    }
}
```

```
package com.sd.usermanagement.controller;

import com.sd.usermanagement.dto.LoginDTO;
import com.sd.usermanagement.service.LoginService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

@RestController
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
public class LoginController {
    private final LoginService loginService;

    @Autowired
    public LoginController(LoginService loginService) {
        this.loginService = loginService;
    }

    @PostMapping("/login")
    public ResponseEntity<Map<String, String>> login(@RequestBody LoginDTO loginDTO) {

        Map<String, String> jsonResponse = new HashMap<>();
        jsonResponse.put("token", loginService.login(loginDTO));

        return ResponseEntity.ok(jsonResponse);
    }
}
```

```
package com.sd.usermanagement.controller;

import com.sd.usermanagement.dto.UserDTO;
import com.sd.usermanagement.service.UserService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
public class RegisterController {
    private final UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    public RegisterController(UserService userService) {
        this.userService = userService;
    }

    @PostMapping("/register")
    public UserDTO register(@RequestBody UserDTO userDTO) {
        return userService.save(userDTO);
    }
}
```

```
package com.sd.usermanagement.controller;

import com.sd.usermanagement.dto.UserDTO;
import com.sd.usermanagement.security.JWTGenerator;
import com.sd.usermanagement.service.UserService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.DeleteMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PutMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.util.List;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/users")
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
public class UserController {
    private final UserService userService;
    private final JWTGenerator jwtGenerator;

    @Autowired
    public UserController(final UserService userService, JWTGenerator jwtGenerator) {
        this.userService = userService;
        this.jwtGenerator = jwtGenerator;
    }

    @GetMapping("/username/{username}")
    public UserDTO getByUsername(@PathVariable String username) {
        return userService.getByUsername(username);
    }

    @GetMapping("/all")
    public List<UserDTO> getAll() {
        return userService.getAll();
    }

    @PutMapping("/update")
    public void update(@RequestBody UserDTO userDTO) {
        userService.update(userDTO);
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/delete/{username}")
    public void delete(@PathVariable String username) {
        userService.delete(username);
    }

    @GetMapping("/role")
    public String getRole(@RequestAttribute("jwtToken") String jwtToken) {
        return jwtGenerator.extractUserRole(jwtToken);
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for your understanding.

I attempted Spring Security integration, but found it unnecessary as my application relies solely on JWT authentication and authorization. In this context, web configuration should be adequate.

The login is successful, and it produces a JWT. However, I encounter a CORS-related error when attempting to extract the user role from it.

[cors error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OtIcu.png)